# Disable CALayer mask frame change animations

Tags: ios, swift3, core-animation, calayer

I have a `CAShapeLayer` instance with a non nil CALayer `mask`. I'm trying to use the frame of that mask to clip the shape. Which works fine. But when I change the frame, I don't want it to animate the frame change. I update the frame in my view's `layoutSubviews` and I've noticed something interesting:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    ...
    if let futureMask = self.futureShape.mask {
        "0.future position animation \(futureMask.animation(forKey: "position"))".print()
        futureMask.removeAllAnimations()
        futureMask.add(CAAnimation(), forKey: "position")
        futureMask.add(CAAnimation(), forKey: "bounds")
        "1.future position animation \(futureMask.animation(forKey: "position"))".print()
        let nowX = computeNowX()
        futureMask.frame = CGRect(x: box.left + nowX, y: box.top, width: box.width - nowX, height: box.height)
        "2.future position animation \(futureMask.animation(forKey: "position"))".print()
    }
}
```

The output this produces looks like:

```
0.future position animations Optional(<CABasicAnimation:0x174624ac0; duration = 0.25; fillMode = backwards; timingFunction = default; keyPath = position; fromValue = NSPoint: {418.94695306710298, 14}>)
1.future position animation Optional(<CAAnimation:0x170625780; duration = 0.25>)
2.future position animation Optional(<CABasicAnimation:0x170625820; duration = 0.25; fillMode = backwards; timingFunction = default; keyPath = position; fromValue = NSPoint: {418.94695306710298, 14}>)
```

At the beginning it's a `CABasicAnimation`, pointing at the `position` keyPath, and with a 250 millisecond duration. I blow it away (via `removeAllAnimations()`) and add a stub CAAnimation hoping that will do nothing. And the `1` print shows that that indeed takes place. But after I set the `frame` property, it has returned to the original. It seems that just setting the frame resets these animations.

Is there no way to set the frame without having these animations take place? I want other animations in the system to keep working. I just want this particular masking layer to not animate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just call layer `removeAllAnimations()` **AFTER** setting the frame.

```
class GradientView: UIView {

  private(set) var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    super.init(frame: frame)
    layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("not implemented")
  }

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    gradientLayer.removeAllAnimations() // remove implicit animation from frame change
  }

}
```

Comment: This is a much better answer.

Answer (score 8):

In the end, the only thing I've found that worked was doing the following:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    ...
    if let futureMask = self.futureShape.mask {
        let nowX = computeNowX()
        CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
        futureMask.frame = CGRect(x: box.left + nowX, y: box.top, width: box.width - nowX, height: box.height)
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

Basically, I just wrapped the setting of the frame with the `CATransaction` calls to disable actions and forced a commit.

UPDATED

@Hlung's answer is more correct. After the setting of `remove`, there are two animations that have been added (as shown by printing `animationKeys()` at that point). I added the following extension method to capture the pattern:

```
extension CALayer {
    func dontAnimate(_ closure:(CALayer) -> ()) {
        closure(self)
        self.removeAllAnimations()
    }
}
```

This allows me to write code like:

```
self.someSubLayer.dontAnimate { layer in layer.frame = whatever }
```

A more powerful variant of `dontAnimate` might first snapshot the current animations, run the `closure`, and *then* `removeAllAnimations()` followed by restoring the snapshotted ones.

Comment: I find this is not a good solution. `CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)` can impact every layers GLOBALLY. Using this, I encounter weird animations and layout all over the app e.g. view controller push doesn't animate, system tabbar somehow doesn't respect bottom safeArea anymore. Even I restore setDisableActions back to previous value, it still doesn't help. What worked for me is just call `layer.removeAllAnimations()` after setting `layer.frame`. I'll add a new answer.